# Second line of the footnote aligned left

Tags: footmisc

I have used the `footmisc` package, in order to suppress the indentation at the beginning of my footnotes.

```
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{15pt}
```

So, the first line begins with the number, and then the text of the footnote.

The thing is, I would like the second (and third, and fourth, and so forth) line of the note to be aligned left, under the number of the footnote.

It would be great if you could help me!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove hang option:

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
```

and it should be fine.